# iOS - Opening a specific page in Settings app using openURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, openurl

We know that on iOS 8 and above, we can direct users to the Settings app by using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

When this method is called, the user will be directed to our own app's settings page within the Settings app.

Is it possible to direct the user to a different page within the Settings app? For example, the Settings -> Touch ID & Passcode page within the Settings app.

If directing to a specific page is not possible, is it possible to at least direct to the home page of Settings app, instead of the settings page of our own app? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't redirect to a specific page of Settings.app since iOS5 or iOS6.

Comment: @Larme thank you. I'm wondering why they removed this functionality. I want to prompt the user to set up touch ID, right now the user gets directed to our own app's setting page, then they need to hit the back button, then click "Touch ID & Passcode" - overall very confusing experience..

Comment: not a solution but perhaps add a tutorial page with screenshots to show how the user can setup Passcode.